# 415 Unsupported Media Type Ajax to Spring boot

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring-boot

I have two problems, which will surely go hand in hand, and that after trying everything I have been seeing everywhere still does not work.

I have this class:

```
public class AuthorDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String description;
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
}
```

And this controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authors/rest")
public class AuthorRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response save(@RequestBody AuthorDTO authorDto) {

        Response response = new Response();

        try {
            response = new Response("Done", authorDto.getId() + ";" + authorDto.getType() + ";"
                     + authorDto.getName() + ";" + authorDto.getDescription() + ";");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = new Response("Error", Constants.Error);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

And this is called from ajax:

```
function save() {
  var authorDto = {
    id : 1,
    name: "NameAuthor",
    description: "DescriptionAuthor",
    type : "TypeAuthor",
    books : [],
  }

  $.ajax({
    url : "authors/rest/save",
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    data : JSON.stringify(authorDto),
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(result) {
      message(result.data);
    },
    error : function(e) {
      message(Error);
    }
  });  
}
```

This, as is, returns an error 415 "Unsupported Media Type".

The thing is that if in the AuthorDTO class I remove the attribute "Set  books", now it does not give me error 415 and it reaches the Controller and the Response returns the data that I passed it through parameters.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Thank you very much.

**SOLUTION:**

Adding the Headers to the ajax call was not high. The problem came from mixing DTO classes with Entity.

I just had to change the attribute

```
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
```

to

```
private Set<BookDTO> books = new HashSet<BookDTO>();
```

and update the Mapper. With this it was solved.

Thank you very much for your response and help.

Comment: Try adding `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/json` in REST Client header section.

Comment: Yes, I already tried `$.ajax({headers: {"Accept" : "application/json","Content-Type" : "application/json"},url : "authors/rest/save",type : "POST",...` and it doesn't work for me either.